# XSLT format-number with comma

Tags: xml, xslt, format

I'm trying to format this and other elements alike, so it would look like this 2,590:

```
<Add_Amount>2,59</Add_Amount>
```

Doing it like this:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="dkk" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
```

....

```
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number(Add_Amount, '#.###,000', 'dkk'), ',', '.')" />
```

And the output comes out NaN. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

//Daniel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Use**:

```
format-number(translate(., ',','.'), '#.###,000', 'd')
```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:decimal-format name="d"
  decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "format-number(translate(., ',','.'), '#.###,000', 'd')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Add_Amount>2,59</Add_Amount>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
2,590
```

**The problem with your code is** that `2,59` isn't a valid number and must be converted to such, before passing this as the first argument of `format-number()`.

Answer (score 4):

The extra call to `translate()` in Dimitre Novatchev's answer seems unnecessary. The use of `<xsl:decimal-format>` should be enough, like this:

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="euroFormat" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(text(), '###.###,00', 'euroFormat')"/>
```

Comment: This is wrong:
    <xsl:decimal-format name="euroFormat" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number('12345,5', '###.###,00', 'euroFormat')"/>
returns NaN

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do this like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number, '#,###')"/>
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, this worked for me
<xso:value-of select="format-number(I_CLAIM_AMOUNT, '#,###,##0.00')"/>

Comment: @gman Because it doesn't work with the given input.