# XSL show result with exponent

Tags: xslt

While adding numbers using `XSL`, it's showing result with `exponent`. For example, if `ProductID` is `1111`

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ProductID + 1000000"/>
```

It's showing something like `1.1111E6`, however I want the result to be `1001111`.

Thanks.

Comment: check for format-number function. You may have some clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758978/xslt-format-number-with-comma

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably using a non-schema-aware transformation, so the value of @ProductID is untyped, which means that when you do arithmetic, the result is an xs:double. If you did integer arithmetic:

```
xs:integer(@ProductID) + 1000000
```

the result would be an xs:integer and would be output as such.

In XPath 1.0 all arithmetic is xs:double arithmetic, but the number-to-string conversion rules hide this fact by requiring "whole numbers" to be output as if they were integers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an XSLT 2.0 processor (all 5-6 different XSLT 1.0 processors I am using produce the wanted answer --  `1001111`.

**With an XSLT 2.0 processor, just convert `@ProductID` to `xs:decimal`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(@ProductID) + 1000000"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t ProductID="1111"/>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
1001111
```

**Do note**:

using the `xs:decimal(someNumber)` constructor and decimal arithmetic guarantees maximum precision of the result, in case `someNumber` can have a non-integer value.

The type `xs:decimal` is a base type for `xs:integer`, that is any `xs:integer` is also an `xs:decimal`, so this solution works also for any integer values.