# Formatting Number string representation in xsl

Tags: xslt, numbers, format

Given a set of 'numbers' 0242, 0980, 0526, 1732, ...

How can I transform them to look like 24,2 98,0 52,6 173,2 ?

I'm trying *xsl:value-of select="format_number(0242,'#,##')*, but that would produce 2,42. With the *'##,#'* the output is 2,4,2

Cheers.

Comment: answer already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3760742/6805256). just add `. div 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a custom decimal format and place it at the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
```

Then you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(0242 div 10, '#,0')"/>
```

to get `24,2` and so on.

---

Alternatively, you could use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number(0242 div 10, '#.0'), '.', ',')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide it by 10 to get the number right, then format it.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(node() div 10, '#.0')" />
```

Please note that I used a dot instead of the comma to use the decimal point operator (for operators see [definition on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp)).